# HashiCorp's Repository for Ubuntu 23.10 is not working (no release file)

Tags: repository

Steps to reproduce

- Installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 23.10 on physical hardware
- Followed [Hashicorp's guide](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/install-cli) for setting up Repo
- Ran apt update
- Get error

```
Ign:6 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com mantic InRelease
Err:7 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.155.216.96 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is this a Hashicorp issue? Or have I not set up the repo correctly?

Comment: https://www.hashicorp.com/official-packaging-guide?product_intent=terraform doesn't list Mantic, so they probably haven't started packaging for it yet

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, i wonder why
[image: this is the link from the repository, i visited it]

There are no links there, unlike actual Ubuntu sources.
And the Hashicorp's guide link in the post talks about how to install Terraform, so it's very confusing.

Anyway, check your `sources.list` and delete the `#` before `deb-src`. This almost always worked for me.

Comment: It works for other distros, so the URL itself is fine. I think they just haven't added mantic yet

Comment: @madacoda It could be, after all it was released just 6 days ago. And why do you even want a newer version? I use 22.04 and i'm quite happy with it. Maybe you just want it because it's a new release?